# Converting SQL dates to different formats

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timezone-offset, type-conversion

I have a task which should be easy, just converting dates in to a specfic format

```
2015-11-16T20:34:19+08:00
```

(`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+[timezone offset]`)  which I later export to an Excel template that requires this type for format.

Looking at the database table where all the data is stored I noticed the column where the dates are stored under is of `Varchar(20)` datatype. As far as I know, it's a bad thing to save dates like that.

So basically what I need is to convert the following:

```
   SELECT TIMESTAMP AS LASTCHANGEDATE FROM TABLE1
```

To a `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+[timezone offset]` format, but TIMESTAMP has the datatype of `varchar(20)`

Anyone can help with this?

**EDIT**

The dates are stored atm like this **23.12.2015 17:08:18**

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server it is something like this:

EDIT: Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @dtString VARCHAR(100) = '23.12.2015 17:08:18';
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @dtString, 104);
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@dt,126)+'+08:00';
```

The reason why I tried the direct cast was your "The dates are stored **atm** like this". I thought, if the occur in different formats it might be better not to specify it...

Old Code:

```
DECLARE @dtString VARCHAR(100) = '23.12.2015 17:08:18';
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = CAST(@dtString AS DATETIME);
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@dt,126)+'+08:00';
```

EDIT: the third parameter of CONVERT is 126. This will create a [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compliant date equivalent

The result:

```
2015-12-23T17:08:18+08:00
```

EDIT: According to your comment you might implement this like here.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(TimeStamp VARCHAR(100),item INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('23.12.2015 17:08:18',1123)
,('23.12.2015 19:08:18',1123)
,('24.12.2015 17:08:18',1123)
,('22.12.2015 19:08:18',3233)

SELECT item, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CONVERT(DATETIME,TimeStamp,104),126)+'08:00' AS ConvertedDate
FROM @tbl 
WHERE item IN (1123,3233,2342);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the fast response. 
When i try your code. I get this following error:
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: @MishMish, Is it SQL Server? You are right, the direct cast in the second line is culture specific. In my country this is working. Edited my answer...

Comment: Yes it's a msssql server and thank you, it works perfectly now, i will try it with my solution

Comment: One last question, how do I use your above example in a query which is stored in a stored procedure looking like this:

Select TimeStamp From Table1 where item in (1123,3233,2342)

Timestamp is the the column with the varchar datatype